# Difference between .manifest vs .mf files

Tags: manifest

What is the difference between .manifest files and .mf files and is there
any relation between .xml files and .manifest files?

Please explain with an example rather than posting links to different websites.

Comment: Manifest files where? Are you talking about Firefox plugins? Or about MANIFEST.MF in Java's `.jar` files? Or about HTML manifests?

Comment: I know about the manifest.mf files in jars but recently i came across xxx.manifest files which looks like xml files. So i wanted to know the difference between them .

Comment: If it says `<?xml` at the beginning of a file, it is most likely an XML file. But there's no such thing as a ".mf" or ".manifest" file without a context. Because I can take any file I please and rename it to ".mf". The important thing is what the program expects, which reads the file. And you didn't mention that, so your question is unanswerable.

Comment: alright then . so i will assume that xyz.manifest is same as xyz.xml . Thanks for your interest :)